# React & Redux Reducer not changin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React app built using Redux and React I'm trying to post data. Everything works fine, but I don't know why the reducer doesn't return the action.  Does that make sense if I render fetch function after post function? I don't think react works like this way.

**scr/actions/userAction.js**

```
export function fetchUsers(data) {
            return{
            type: "USERS",
            payload: fetch('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/users',{
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }

            })
            .then(res => res.json())
    }
};

export function postUsers(name, age) {
let users = {
    name,
    age
}
    return{
            type: "USERS_POST",
            payload: fetch('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/users',{
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(users),
            })
            .then(res => res.json())

    }

};
```

**src/reducers/userReducer.js**

```
const initalState = {
fetching: false,
fetched: false,
users: [],
error: null
};
export default function(state=initalState, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case "USERS_PENDING":{
            return {...state, fetching: true,}
        }
        case "USERS_FULFILLED":{
            return {...state, fetching:false, fetched: true, users: action.payload,}
        }
        case "USERS_REJECTED":{
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload,}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_PENDING":{
            return {...state, fetching: true,}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_FULFILLED":{
              return {...state, fetching:false, fetched: true, users: [],}
        }
        case "USERS_POST_REJECTED":{
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload,}
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**src/components/layout.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'; 
import { fetchUsers, postUsers } from '../actions/usersAction';


class Layout extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props) 
    this.state = {  
        name: '',
        age: ''}
}

onUserUpdate(filed, event){
    //console.log('onUserUpdate: ' + filed + '==' + event.target.value);
    if (filed === 'name') {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        })
        return
    }
    if (filed ==='age') {
        this.setState({
            age: event.target.value
        })
        return
    }
}

componentDidMount() {  
  this.props.fetchUsers();
}
  render() {
    const { act } = this.props;

      const fetchUserss = act.users.map(d =>  <tr key={d.id}><td>{d.name}</td><td>{d.age}</td><td></td></tr>);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label>
            name:
              </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'name')} placeholder="Enter Name"/>
                <label>
                age:
              </label>
                <input type="text" name="age" onChange={this.onUserUpdate.bind(this, 'age')} placeholder="enter username"/>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.postUsers(this.state.name,this.state.age)}>Add News</button>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>Name</th>
                  <th>age</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 {fetchUserss}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
  }
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        act: state.users,
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({fetchUsers, postUsers}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Layout);
```

**Please let me know if I miss out any information.**

If this has already been asked, I would greatly appreciate if you are able to point me in the right direction.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your `action`'s types dont match `reducers`'s actions type.

Comment: Fetch doesn't return the data, it returns a `Promise` which resolves to your data. You're returning an action with a `Promise` as the value instead of the value you're expecting. I would suggest reading [*Async Actions - Redux*](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)

Comment: @TheReason I'm using redux-promise-middleware

Comment: the type of action of your action: fetchUsers is "USERS" and there is no implementation of that action in your reducer.

Comment: ops... I just read the documentation of the package... this pck adds _PENDING and FULLFILLED by its own... sorry

Comment: @LuisNolazco yes it is I can't put in action USERS_POST_FULFILLED he will read it USERS_POST_FULFILLED_FULFILLED

Comment: What I find it weird is to see the structure of your switch case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from the example of @Luis Nolazco It's really helped me, I should put action.payload into square brackets

```
case "USERS_POST_FULFILLED":{
          return {...state, fetching: false,fetched: true, users:[...state.users, action.payload],}
    }
```

here's the example [codesandbox.io/s/MQZWLJloA](http://codesandbox.io/s/MQZWLJloA) by @Luis Nolazco

Answer (score 1):

your switch case looks weird:

```
case "USERS_FULFILLED":{
    return {...state, users: action.payload}
}

case "USERS_POST_FULFILLED":{
    return action.payload;
}
case "USERS_POST_DELETE_FULFILLED":{
    return {...state, users: action.payload}
}
```

why do you use brachets?
it should be:

```
switch (action.type) {
   case 'USERS_FULLFILED':
       return { ...state, users: action.payload };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't do this way I'll get an error "Failed to compile" https://ibb.co/kpZK96

Comment: Yeah Luis, you have an extra colon there

Comment: I created an example with static data: https://codesandbox.io/s/MQZWLJloA

Comment: Thank you I found the solution from this example, I should put action.payload into square brackets like this return {...state, users:[...state.users, action.payload],}